# Сортировка списка по двум параметрам

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать список координат `(x, y, z)` по двум параметрам:

1. Весь список отсортирован по возрастанию координаты `Z`
2. Кортежи с одинаковыми координатами `Z` в свою очередь сортируются по убыванию координаты `Y`

На входе:

```
[(3, 11, 14), (3, 9, 18), (3, 10, 10), (3, 11, 12), (3, 11, 10), (3, 10, 12), (3, 9, 14)]
```

На выходе:

```
[(3, 11, 10), (3, 10, 10), (3, 11, 12), (3, 10, 12), (3, 11, 14), (3, 9, 14), (3, 9, 18)]
```

Код:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
coord = [(3, 11, 14), (3, 9, 18), (3, 10, 10), (3, 11, 12), (3, 11, 10), (3, 10, 12), (3, 9, 14)]
for key, groups in groupby(sorted(coord, key=lambda z: z[2]), lambda z: z[2]):
    for group in sorted(groups, key=lambda y: y[1], reverse=True):
        result.append(group)
print(result)
# [(3, 11, 10), (3, 10, 10), (3, 11, 12), (3, 10, 12), (3, 11, 14), (3, 9, 14), (3, 9, 18)]
```

Какие еще могут быть варианты решений?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
coord = [(3, 11, 14), (3, 9, 18), (3, 10, 10), (3, 11, 12), (3, 11, 10), (3, 10, 12), (3, 9, 14)]
print(sorted(coord, key=lambda point: (point[2], -point[1])))
```